# Processing 3: Manual Webcam Pixel Manipulation

Tags: java, processing, video-capture

I'm trying to manipulate the pixels in my video so I called the pixels manually. It's frozen every time I've tried to run the program. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

```
import processing.video.*;

Capture cam;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  cam = new Capture (this,displayWidth, displayHeight, 30);
  smooth();
  cam.start();
}
void captureEvent(Capture cam) {
  cam.read();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  cam.loadPixels();
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      int loc = x+y*width;
      pixels[loc] = cam.pixels[loc]/2;
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: What is the order of events here? Are you sure `captureEvent()` is happening before `draw()` is called? How big is this image? Iterating over every single pixel in a video 60 times per second seems like a huge job, so I'm not surprised it freezes.

Comment: Also, you're never calling `loadPixels()` on the sketch itself, so you can't use the sketch's `pixels` array.

Comment: @KevinWorkman was right. It works now.